# Get values from db where column is '1'

Tags: c#, sql

I'm doing a project for my OOP Class, using C# with SQL Server, and I think I'm not coding the best way... I don't want code, just some guidance on how to improve my code.

For example: I have the following treeView that will populate a datagridview according with the selected node. In the database, there are columns with datatype bit (i.e. `bool`) to know if it's a client, supplier or collaborator.

1. All Records

   1.1 Client

   1.2 Suplier

   1.3 Collaborator

For now, I have methods to get data for each node:

```
public DataTable GetEntriesData()
    {
        ClearDgv();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("" +
                "SELECT Cod, " +
                "name, " +

                "phone + ' / ' + mobile as Contact," +

                "cropLastReview as LastReview" +

                "FROM tb_Registers", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dtRegisters.Load(reader);

            }

        }
        return dtRegisters;
    }
public DataTable GetSuppliersData()
    {
        ClearDgv();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("" +
                "SELECT Cod, " +
                "Name, " +

                "phone+ ' / ' + mobile as Contact," +

                "cropLastReview as lastReview" +

                "FROM tb_registers where isSupplier= '1'", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dtRegisters.Load(reader);

            }

        }
        return dtRegisters;
    }
 public DataTable GetClientsData() //method to get data from sql database
    {
        ClearDgv();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("" +
                "SELECT Cod, " +
                "Name, " +

                "phone+ ' / ' + mobile as Contact," +

                "cropLastReview as LastReview" +

                "FROM tb_registers where isClient= '1'", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dtRegisters.Load(reader);

            }

        }
        return dtRegisters;
    }
public DataTable GetCollaboratorsData()
    {
        ClearDgv();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("" +
                "SELECT Cod, " +
                "name, " +

                "phone + ' / ' + mobile as Contact," +

                "cropLastReview as lastReview" +

                "FROM tb_registers where isCollaborator= '1'", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dtRegisters.Load(reader);

            }

        }
        return dtRegisters;
    }


 private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_DgvName.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        this.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;

        RefreshHome();}

public void RefreshHome() //populate/change datagridv style according to the selected treeview.node
    {
        switch (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
        {
            case "All Records":
                dgv_Clients.DataSource = GetEntriesData();
                tablessControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                NumOfEntries();
                DgvStyle1();

                break;
            case "Clients":
                tablessControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                dgv_Clients.DataSource=GetClientsData();
                NumOfEntries();
                DgvStyle1();
                break;
        }
case "Suppliers":
                tablessControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                dgv_Clienes.DataSource = GetSuppliersData();
                NumOfEntries();
                DgvStyle1();
                break;
            case "Collaborators":
                tablessControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                dgv_Clients.DataSource = GetCollaboratorsData();
                NumOfEntries();
                DgvStyle1();
                break;
     }
```

The code is working fine, but I want a "cleaner" way to do this. Maybe code in SQL?

Comment: What do your `GetSuppliersData` and `GetCollaboratorsData` functions look like? Are the queries identical except for the where clause?

Comment: yes, they're identical except for the where clause.. thats the point, looks like duplicated code for me..

Comment: Ok.. it'd probably help to add those functions to your code sample then. It's difficult to surmise that from your current sample.

Comment: sry about that, i edited because my code is in portuguese... was missing a empty space between clause where and tb_registers.

Comment: Can we Linq this or querry are mandatory?

Comment: @Abbas I've rolled back you last edit, see this [meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/should-you-edit-someone-elses-code-in-a-question)

Comment: @Ludisposed ok, I understand, I (mistakenly) thought I was helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the code in question has for each method in common is that it

- calls `ClearDgv()` which seems to be just a call to clear a datagrid view
- accesses some sql server and execute a query
- fills the `DataTable` variable `dtRegisters` which seems to be a class level variable

The call to `ClearDgv()` make me assume that the data access code is living in a `Form` which makes the `Form` class having to many responsibilities. You should separate the presentation (your form)  from the data access by having a second class.

If you wouldn't fill `dtRegisters` with the result of the query you could make the methods static, because they wouldn't change the state of the class.

By extracting the data access code into a new method which just takes the `connectionString` and a sql statement you could remove lots of duplicated code.

You are using `using` which is a good thing to do but could be improved by stacking the `using`'s like in the provided code below.

By using the `var` type at places where it's type is obvious from the right hand of the assignment will make the code easier to refactor and faster to write as well.

```
public static DataTable FetchData(string sqlStatement, string connectionString)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var table = new DataTable():
        table.Load(reader);
        return table;
    }
}
```

which can be called out of your `Getxxx` methods like so

```
public DataTable GetEntriesData()
{
    ClearDgv();
    dtRegisters = FetchData("SELECT Cod, name, phone + ' / ' + mobile as Contact, cropLastReview as LastReview FROM tb_Registers", connectionString);
    return dtRegisters;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted !!! with your and @Robh answear i managed to clean about 200 lines of code !!

Thanks you !!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to keep your SQL queries as part of your code, you should pull them out into named constants. You can also use a verbatim string literal to keep them nicely formatted:

```
private const string SuppliersQuery = @"
SELECT Cod, 
       Name, 
       phone + ' / ' + mobile as Contact,
       cropLastReview as lastReview
FROM   tb_registers 
where isSupplier = '1'";
```

It also looks neater if you use consistent capitalisation. E.g. `where` should really be `WHERE`. Although, I don't do all capitals SQL - I've never really seen the benefit.

Combined with [Heslacher's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/182199/22816):

```
public DataTable GetSuppliersData()
{
    ClearDgv();
    dtRegisters = FetchData(SuppliersQuery, connectionString);
    return dtRegisters;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! didnt know about this const string thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider not embedding any SQL in your C# code. You are basically splitting your application logic across layers. You then deny yourself (or your DBA) the ability to optimize SQL code without changing your application.

I would strongly consider using a stored procedure (or maybe stored procedure**s**). You could have a single that returns multiple resultsets which you can then assign to each `DataTable`. This is OK when the data are small enough that front-loading everything at once is faster. But if you have much more data that your UI could end up hanging then it may make sense to have a parameterized stored procedure. In your case, you seem to be using only one table with different filters, so you could just pass in a parameter to specify which data you want and return only that subset. Split stored procedures can be more beneficial for getting data from different tables or where logic is simply too different than simply different parameters for a `WHERE` clause. Either way, a parameterized stored procedure or multiple stored procedures enables you to respond to user's action (e.g. expanding a node on your treeview for instance). All you should need in your C# is the name of the procedure and the parameter(s) of stored procedure. You should know nothing about the tables or columns being used to build the query within C#.

Another point. You have a hard-coded `switch` in your C#. Suppose your client come to you say, "hey, we wanna a 5th category." Should we really reply, "Sure, let me reprogram the application."? I think not. This is also data. Your application should be relying on the database to tell how many categories there are by doing *another* query to ask for the categories then build the treeview's second-level nodes based on that. Then you run the query to get the data for records under each 2nd level node. This enables you to scale your application and add more categories simply by inserting few more rows in your database. No upgrade of application required.